# Powershell to Select-String a Variable and output to another variable and file

Tags: powershell

```
    $captureRaw | $rowcount=Select-String -Pattern "closed,\s([\d,\.]+)" -AllMatches | % {  $_.Matches } | % { $_.Groups[1].value}
    echo $rowcount > $output_file
```

I am trying to run a select-string on a variable and then hold the extracted select-string in a new variable as well as outputting the results to a file.

But i cannot get the above code to work together so if i remove $captureRaw and the pipe and insert a -path it works but i want to be able to search a variable and output the extracted data to a new variable ($rowcount) and output this to file as well.

Thanks

Comment: Tried this? $rowcount = $captureRaw | Select-String -Pattern "closed,\s([\d,\.]+)" -AllMatches | % {  $_.Matches } | % { $_.Groups[1].value}

Comment: I did try this but then i don't get an output for $rowcount

Comment: Could you provide a sample of input and expected output?